# Error running Node program. module 'prompt' not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to a quadratic equation with Node.js. I have a file named 'discriminant.js' which will simply calculate the discriminant value on supplying parameters.
I have another file named 'qudratic.js' which will simply return the roots values after calculation.
And finally I have a file named 'solve.js' with following code :

```
var quad = require('./qudratic');

var prompt = require('prompt');

prompt.get(['a','b','c'], function(err, result){

if (err) {return onErr(err);}
console.log('Command-line input received');
console.log('a' + result.a);
console.log('b' + result.b);
console.log('c' + result.c);
});

 quad(result.a,result.b,result.c, function(err, quadsolve){
    if (err){
       console.log('Error:', err)
     }
    else{
          console.log("Roots are "+quadsolve.root1() + " "+        quadsolve.root2());
        }

   });
```

When I run : **node solve**  following error comes up:

```
quad(result.a,result.b,result.c, function(err, quadsolve){
 ^

ReferenceError: result is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sijan/workspace...../NODE/first/node_modules/solve.js:15:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
at startup (node.js:136:18)
at node.js:963:3
```

Comment: result is inside the prompt callback and quad is outside it. So result will be undefined. move the quad code inside the callback.

Comment: Yeah. Big mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`result` is inside the `prompt` callback and `quad` is outside it. So `result` will be `undefined`.

Move the `quad` code inside the callback.